# What is the real name of Hinduism? Also what is the meaning of its real name?

Tags: vedas, dharma

I read that Hindu is foreign word and  However, the Persians could not pronounce the letter "S" correctly in their native tongue and mispronounced it as "H." Thus, for the ancient Persians, the word "Sindhu" became "[Hindu](http://www.shraddhananda.com/Meaning_and_Origin_Of_The_Word_Hindu.html)."

So what is the real name of Hindu Dharma? Also what is the meaning of its real name?

Comment: @Bharat The link of the question you suggested does not contain the meaning of it on your link. So I just wanted people to know the meaning of our real Dharma and its name too, That is why I wrote this page. Anyways, Thank you for your activeness.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: if you carefully read all the answers of that question, you will find what you are looking for. IMHO this is a duplicate.

Comment: Dear Pratik, where is the meaning written?

Comment: - Prior to that, the practitioners of the native religion of India called their religion, ‘Sanãtan Dharma’ – the Eternal Religion. It was known as eternal, because the Truths revealed by it are true today, were true before this universe existed, and will be true even after the destruction of the universe.
- **To the native, i.e ancestors of today's Hindus, their religion was just called Dharma. Dharma came in many flavors like Sanathana Dharma with it's various sects, Buddha Dharma & Jina Dharma with their sects.**

Comment: This is not meaning. Dharma's meaning is religion. What I am asking is the meaning of Hinduism or its actual name which is sanatana Dharma.

Comment: Eternal Religion. Case closed

Comment: Yes, but these two words, I did not find in that question, that's why I asked and answered this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Vedas the Dharma is said to be *"Sanatana Dharma"* - Eternal Truth.

Some people consider `Sanatana Dharma` as `"Aadi Sanatana Devi Devta Dharma"` means oldest one Dharma that teaches one to behave like Devi Devta (Deity).

In Mahabharata, the Dharma is to be said "Aarya Dharma" and the india as "Aarya Vrata".

*Edit is invited as this is wiki.*

Comment: Also look: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13752/277

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Hinduism or Hindu are foreign or more precisely Persian origin words and they have same etymoloy as you mention in your question. The proper and original name of Hinduism is Sanatan Dharma which translates to the Eternal Religion or the Eternal Faith. It is called so because Sanatan Dharma is not based on any sectarianism but on fundamental truths which hold true for all mankind and in all ages.