# According to Advaita philosophy , what is the meaning of word Dharma?

Tags: dharma

What is the meaning of word Dharma as used by Sri Krishna in Bhagwat Gita sloka 
"yada yada hi dharmasya
glanir bhavati bharata
abhyutthanam adharmasya
tadatmanam srjamy aham"?

If there are multiple meanings depending upon dvaita or advaita understanding then I will like to know the definition of word Dharma from Advaita point of view.

Do animals also have a dharma ?

Is there anything which is beyond Dharma?

Comment: You seem to be asking too many Qs under one Q. Your title is Q1. Do animals have...? is Q2. Is there anything beyond Dharma is Q3. And these Qs may or may not be related to each other. Also u have a Q4 ( Does the defn. vary with philosophies?}

Comment: So what do you want me to do ? The questions are related to my stream of thought. It will become apparent when answers are given.

Comment: I don't think the meaning of Dharma varies with the different Vedanta. (I mean It's not like Vedanta Acharya e.g Adi Shankara has given his own interpretation of Dharma. In other words, Dharama is a universal/central concept) We already have couple of useful Q/A : [What is Dharma according to the Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/289/277) and [What is Dharma according to Veda or Upanishad?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13752/277).

Comment: Valmiki Ramayana says, "Raamo vigrahavan dharmaha" i.e. Rama is dharma personified.  What is the meaning of the sentence "Rama is Dharma personified."? Can I be Dharma personified ? If yes how?

Comment: @DheerajVerma if you have any problem with understanding any of verses like you've mentioned, you can [ask a question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :) or feel free to discuss in chat rooms.

Comment: @Pandya I am satisfied with the answer to the question [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13752/what-is-dharma-according-to-veda-or-upanishad)

Comment: So what do you want me to do ? -- Since u have asked. At least ask this Q separately: "Is there a Dharma for the animals?" as it has no relation whatsoever to ur title Q. "According to....?" @DheerajVerma