# What is my religion?

Tags: culture, name, terminology

I was watching Satguru (Jaggi Vasudev) video on YouTube where he said that Hindu is not a religion, its a geographical identity and that's why all part of India follows different practices and have different gods. When foreign invaders arrived they had to classify Indian religion so they called Indians collectively as "Hindus".

So my question is:

If I am not a Hindu (assuming the above statement to be true) then what is my religion? Do we have any further classification mentioned in books? or caste ?

Comment: yes, the word Hindu was given by foreigners referring to those who live beyond Sindhu river (now in Pakistan). over time, Sindh became Hind. Your religion depends on which God and Book your family follows.

Comment: Your first question is already asked about the origin of the word Hindu [What is the origin of the word “Hindu”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/65/5212). It's better to remove it.

Comment: that being said, while 'sadhguru' tries his best to safeguard traditional values (and I'm glad someone with a following and a microphone is doing it), many of his explanations are wrong.. and what's worse, people believe that these claims with confidence have scriptural backing

Comment: @ram although I don't know who is the 'sadhguru' you are talking about, but I feel your comment of "many of his explanations are wrong.. " needs citation to support your argument.

Comment: @Vineet, https://www.youtube.com/user/sadhguru - he claimed recently in a talk about beef eating in North-East, that only cows are protected from slaughter, not bulls. that is just misleading. he has a really large following, so he must watch what he says.

Comment: also see - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014#18014

Comment: The term 'Hindus' is a term usually referred to by followers of the Santana Dharma. Orthodox (Astika) Hindus share three assertions. 1) They believe in God. 2) they believe that the Vedas are the revealed truths of God. 3) They believe in cycles and reincarnation.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Answer in that question confirms what I heard, in that case my second question is valid.

Comment: To remove closure of duplicate and too broad, I am removing first question from your question. Please post only one question per post.

Answer (score 5):

Hinduism is a religion and in old times, it was known as Sanatan Dharma.

Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna / Volume 2  / [Visit To The Sinthi Brahmo Samaj](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_2/32_sinthi_brahmo_samaj.htm):

> The Hindu religion alone is the Sanatana Dharma. The various creeds you hear of nowadays have come into existence through the will of God and will disappear again through His will. They will not last forever. Therefore I say, 'I bow down at the feet of even the modern devotees.' The Hindu religion has always existed and will always exist.

Comment: Nice reference found. Shri Ramakrshna was divine. Thanks. Any reference in Upanishads or Vedas or an ancient sanskrt literature?

Comment: @Vineet yes, visit [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13757/277)